# Error Compiling cocos2d-x 3.14.1 for Android Studio : Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag ‘cocos’ in import path

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to run cpp-test example project, which is packed in the cocos2d-x 3.14.1 download, on Android Studio. I'm following this tutorial : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/installation/Android-Studio/, which requires complete this first: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/installation/Android-terminal/index.html.

However, I got error when run 
`python android-build.py -p 22 cpp-tests`:

I got this log from cmd :

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-22 is larger than android:minSdkVersi
on 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: D:\cocos2d-x-3.14.1

Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cocos' in import path

Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?

Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
make: Entering directory `D:/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tests/cpp-tests/proj.android'
jni/Android.mk:170: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `D:/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tests/cpp-tests/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2.
Build dynamic library for project [ D:\cocos2d-x-3.14.1\build\..\tests\cpp-tests
 ] failed!
```

I tried another way to compile the project for Android Studio following Sonar Systems's tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdOkbXYsf04 . And I got the same error.

```
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: D:\cocos2d-x-3.14.1

Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cocos' in import path

Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?

Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
make: Entering directory `D:/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tests/cpp-tests/proj.android-studi
o/app'
jni/Android.mk:170: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `D:/cocos2d-x-3.14.1/tests/cpp-tests/proj.android-studio
/app'
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

A part of the `Android.mk` file of the example project:

```
../../../Classes/SpriteFrameCacheTest/SpriteFrameCacheTest.cpp \
../../../Classes/controller.cpp \
../../../Classes/testBasic.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../..

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos)
```

I'm using:
Windows 7

Android Studio 2.2.3.

Cocos2d-x 3.14.1

Python 2.7.13

Ant 1.10.1

NDK r13b

Any solution for this please?

Comment: Try this: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-link-prebuilt-cocos2d-x-c-library-to-android-studio-project/32949/11?u=piotrros

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but I'm trying to run an existing sample project, how could it relate to link pre-built library?

Comment: It's just an easier way to use cocos. Because you can use the full potential of Android Studio. Debugging for example. @Kaizer Sozay told you what's wrong with your compilation.

Comment: @Makalele , thanks for your advice, I'll have a look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it seems you are not reading the errors

First:

> Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory:
>   D:\cocos2d-x-3.14.1
>
> Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cocos' in
>   import path
>
> Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly
>   defined ?
>
> Android NDK: The following directories were searched: Android NDK:

You must setup cocos properly - run setup.py , and make sure your Android NDK path is pointing to the right directory. Likewise make sure ANT and Python are in the right directories.

Second:

> Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-22 is larger than
>   android:minSdkVersi on 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml

Either change the platform, or the minimum sdk...

If you do not even read the errors, how can you possibly solve your problem.... Bye! :D

Comment: thanks for your reply. About the 1st errors: I'm pretty sure that NDK, Ant and Python path is correct, I double checked it. It's weird that it run without any problem on my friend's PC, which uses Windows 10. Therefore, I think the problem isn't caused by incorrect directory path.

Comment: thanks to your advice I fixed it by uninstall everything, delete all Environment Variable and set it all up from the beginning for 3 or 4 times. I also move cocos2d-x 3.14.1 to another folder( from D:\cocos2d-x 3.14.1 to D:\cocos2d-x\cocos2d-x 3.14.1).

And that fixed it, I still have no idea why but I'm pretty sure everything is the same.

Comment: haha the error wouldn't be there unless there was a problem.... you probably set the correct path this time round...